# Maintaining an advantage in a world of infinite acceleration capabilites

Tags: science-based, technology, spaceships

#### Technical

Suppose that someone showed up very few years ago and started selling out spaceships ships are capable of arbitrarily high acceleration, the drive is integral to the hull and moves the whole ship not just some point on/in it so structural stresses are not a limit to acceleration.

While the engine/hull is in action, the hull is energized in such a way that one can't use attach anything on them or use them to push anything - they'll burn anything that touches the hull outside (thus, no free unlimited energy for you by using one to run a stone-mill by driving a horse on circular track)

#### Social context

They are selling them to whoever can pay the price and have the prior approval of international space authorities. To secure the right to sell without troubles, each nation with a stable uncontested government was granted, without charge, two such hulls/ships able to fit a spherical payload of 7238.22947387 cubic meters. The selling price is quite high, though, so most of the multinationals were able to buy an average of 3 such ships.

The result of it is that many corporation started to engage in solar space exploration, by sending unmanned, remote controlled probes at insane accelerations - yes, one can engineer electronics able to support 50,000g+***.

Some squabbles ensued between various multinationals about the claims on resources, and I won't go trough the whole brouhaha, everybody learned how close the humanity was to mutual assured destruction in a Mexican stand-off, using those hull/engines loaded with heavy payloads and threatening to launch them close to luminal speeds against anyone who don't agree with them.

**Today, in the news:** the international space authorities decided that, for anyone to have a valid claim on discovered resources:

1. the claim needs to be made by a human, present at the place that is claimed and...
2. the claim can be made for a spatial extent no larger than whatever fits in a radius equal with a circle that the human (using whatever means) is able to *completely* travel in a given time (the price for the license to use the claim varies with the amount of time, the minimal value of it is 5 minutes).
3. in the case of competing claims, the winner is the one that *completes first the circle of whatever radius s/he chose* and then *returns to the center of the circle to make the claim* (and then is able to pay the price for the license)

#### Question

What *today* technologies (both in terms of material artifacts and techniques) would any party - nation or private entity - could use to gain an advantage in bringing a human in a situation s/he is able to make a *valid* claim? Heavy surgery is allowed, as long as the human subjected to it maintains intact:

- the nervous system
- all the bones of her/his body (bone reinforcement is allowed as long as the bones are not entirely replaced). Limb amputation is allowed, but that's the maximum extent of bone removal.

---

*** equipment able to withstand high-g - [they done it in 1941, for proximity fuses that were meant for anti-aircraft artillery, with electronic tubes no less](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_fuze#Improvement_in_the_US)

---

<sub>Note: this question is an attempt to re-WorldBuild [@Ash's question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/217540/maintaining-an-advantage-in-a-world-of-reactionless-drives?noredirect=1#comment671882_217540) *in a less misleading way*, while obtaining pretty much the same answers.</sub>
<sub><del>This being said, I offer no guarantees that I understood his question enough to come with a mise-en-scène equivalent with his (in regards with the answers that can be obtained).</del> Seems that @Ash says I didn't get it right (oh, well). Even if I didn't get it right, I think my question as it is can stand on its own.</sub>

Comment: Amazon actually bought 5 of them, but Bezos took one for a joy-ride. The last time he was seen, he was mumbling something about showing to Musk who's the toughest. The one he used took off to an acceleration of 1 M-g, very likely that's the last news one is going to hear about Bezos.

Comment: As a response/rewording to my question you failed in the first sentence.

Comment: @Ash Ok, won't be the first, won't be the last.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it's only the hull/structure of the ship that the drive accelerates, not the contents?  So if you pull 50,000 G, all the air inside the hull will occupy a centimeter or less at the local bottom of any sealed compartment?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Haven't verified your numbers, but you're correct in principle.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Oooh I hadn't considered ***THAT***, I need to go away and think about that, thanks.

Comment: You'd be lucky to get to 20-30g with any modern-ish technologies, even with radical surgery. More than that and you're into levels of "cyberborgisation" that simply don't exist and aren't yet on the horizon.

Comment: @Ash "You'd be lucky" I, personally, won't be anything. Neither will you (a _just-in-case_ note: hope you aren't taking/making it personal). Otherwise, if noone comes with an answer that satisfy the requirements in the 7days of bounty, I'll post my answer and you'll be welcome to poke as many holes as you want: bottom line, this is one of the things that make WB.SE attractive (at least for me).

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi This might be a better question with the background and the question seperated more clearly.

Comment: @MontyWild separation of concerns was my intention. I wanted to get rid of "stick it to The Man" situation, the kinetic bombardment at relativistic speeds and the use of technology as an infinite source of unlimited power (side-tracks that I considered misleading), but still maintain a situation of fierce competition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method of making humans more g-tolerant is based on one that I read in [Joe Haldeman's The Forever War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War).  However, this answer may include my own ideas and/or omit various features mentioned in the book.

By immersing a human in a liquid in which they are neutrally-buoyant (Water with a solute content that has the same density as the human body), as g-forces increase, the pressure on the body also increases.  This has the effect of countering [GLOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-LOC) and related effects due to the heart's inability to pump blood to the brain against increased g-forces.

Breathing can take place through a positive pressure system similar to a SCUBA regulator at low to moderate elevated g-forces, potentially up to 100g

Alternatively, for high g-forces in excess of 100g, where the difference in density between air and the immersion fluid or the body's density would itself lead to injuries, the lungs can be filled with similar (sterile, isotonic, non-toxic, equivalent density) immersion fluid, and oxygen (and potentially also nutrients) supplied by external blood oxygenators designed for high-g conditions.

In order that compression of the bodily tissues not result in abdominal or diaphragm tears, ports may be placed in the peritoneum to allow the immersion fluid to enter the abdominal and thoracic cavities.  Intra-cranial pressure can be balanced by a port in the skull and a tube to the ventricles of the brain, which can infuse artificial cerebrospinal fluid.

Once the bulk of the body's soft tissues have been supported in this manner, the only remaining issue is the differential density of the bones, which under high g-forces might cause soft-tissue injuries or may even break.  By inserting one or more sockets into each of the bones and through the skin and soft tissues into which supporting pins can be inserted, the bones can be secured against high g-forces.

At G-forces in excess of a few thousand g, suspended proteins will begin to settle out of suspension.  In order to prevent/alleviate this, the subject could be rotated constantly or periodically so that the direction of acceleration varies constantly, meaning that the proteins will always be moving through the body or cells.

In this manner, it should be possible for a human to survive long-term not just tens of g, but potentially as much as tens of thousands of g.

This should be achievable with current and near-future technology.

It wouldn't be a particularly pleasant way to travel, however.  The traveller would be completely immobilized, and the chief risks would become those of technical failures and mental health issues.

Comment: On an excellent track. Isotonic saline, fill the lungs with the same and suspend the respiratory function, use [custom artificial blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_substitute) with the fine emulsion of PFBOC, an external heart+lungs+kidney (that will take care of maintain the emulsion of PFBOC in parameters at as circulation cycle). The [unmodified bone density](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.3109/02841867809127938) allows for "Looking 4 anorexic healthy women age between 50-60 for space exploration" ads.

Comment: Using a safe percent of deuterated/heavy water (25% _may_ be safe) may allow for further body tissue "density matching". 
Considerations about the sedimentation speed in lab centrifuges would provide an indication about when the g-forces start to become a problem for a normal physiology - looks like proteins need in excess of 5000g for a good while to start sedimenting (can you imagine a countermeasure for it?)

Comment: Are you OK with a "combined answer"? I.e. do you allow me to intervene in (edit) your answer and fill the blanks with my considerations once you are good with the amount of effort that you want to put into it?

Comment: I feel like your eyeballs would get pulled through your brain.

Comment: @DanielB not if the hydrostatic pressure of the cerebral liquid is the same as the one pushing onto your eyes.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi As to protein settling... yes.  Look at my edited answer.

Comment: Under constant rotation in hyper-acceleration conditions, the inner ear needs to go, even if you sedate the payload. I'm afraid for the same reason for which the brain, liver, spline and pancreas will need to be protected by a membrane with a gel underneath, supported the same way as the skeleton - the tug from their attaching point may be minimized hydrostatically, but one can't exclude wear or scarring by the periodic friction with the rest in areas not habitually subject to such friction (the hearth, lungs, intestines with their nervous system intact and kidneys better be left at home)

Comment: Well... more periodic rotation than constant, then.

Comment: Given you can get to a high fraction of C in only hours at a mere 1000 G, there need be no mental health issues to traveling this way -- sedate passenger, apply G amelioration, travel, undo G amelioration, allow passenger to wake, and they've been "asleep" less than a day.

Comment: While you could theoretically subject someone to 10,000 g for a few hours and get pretty close to C, it'd be safer and still not too long to get to a sizeable fraction of C at 2,000 g.

Comment: @MontyWild " it'd be safer and still not too long to get to a sizeable fraction of C at 2,000 g." ... and lose the financial quarter bonus? This is why you didn't get to CEO a big corporation and thus you now indulge in the escapism of WB :D (yes, I verbed CEO)

Answer (score 1):

### Mass dilation

Given a few years of R&D (the same as required for any solution, it could be less if you don't need to work the kinks out) and such a ship (perhaps three ships for direction-changes), you can build a kind of warp-drive.

Mass dilation isn't too practical for bending space without handwavium that can accelerate it arbitrarily fast and in whatever direction. With that (i.e. your drive), you can make your ship-full-of-rock into something which behaves like a black hole by moving fast enough (in a spiral, if you like). This creates a gravitational field, and you freefall all the way.

Given three fully-controllable masses (ships) and no care for the surrounding environment, you can achieve arbitrary acceleration without crushing, in a small volume. (Gravitational waves not only included, but exploited.) The handwavium you've provided makes this a matter of number-crunching rather than exotic science. A bigger not-crushed volume to fit a passenger in just means more chaos inflicted on the surrounding area.

Unfortunately, as soon as this is developed, someone will note that the human isn't really adding anything to the process, and is moving at *c* anyway. So the time-limit becomes a distance-limit, and the only real constraint is getting the human to the middle of your claim if it's a solid mass. 5min at *c* is enough to girdle the Sun, though.

(**NB**: The environmental effects of massive gravitational waves caused by relativistic dispersal of masses will cause this to be banned quickly ... just after the first expedition has made every claim worth making.)

---

#### Frame challenges

Accelerating arbitrary masses to arbitrary velocity is free energy, just needs slightly cleverer engineering. A railgun converts electrical fields into motion, but the principle can apply in reverse. So I'll load up my ship with iron (or superconducting rings, or whatever has nice properties), fly it out to the end of the "barrel", and accelerate it to whatever a convenient velocity is ... kick the load out the cargo doors ... then drain off the energy by bringing the load back to rest. The ship comes back around the long way for another load. There's no real way around this if your "big gun" application of the ships is to be preserved.

Apart from any of that, though - pushing the survivable-acceleration further is only going to get you so far when compared to an earlier launch-date.

---

## Edit

In response to the OP's comment:

This is not far-future-tech of our world. This is thought-experiment tech of "what if we could accelerate a mass arbitrarily fast", which is the function of your engine. It's conceptually *simpler* than a waterwheel, for someone working with relativity.

It uses your given device in a different way, to reduce the effect of inertia rather than reinforcing the passenger.

Comment: It's not about how one develops infinite acceleration and what future development follows as a consequence of that. The question is about "assuming infinite acceleration is available but the cargo/passengers are still bound to inertia, how would one would **apply** _today_'s technologies to ensure a human body take as high as possible acceleration without dying" - no handwavium about what future science/technology surprises await around the corner. It's about "maximizing the value for our shareholders (and the bonuses for CEO) *next quarter* - here and now, pure American capitalism"

Comment: Yes, and that is the question I've answered. This setup requires nothing more than a (big) number cruncher to decide your course, existing models of how space-time warps in the presence of a ridiculous mass, and a small control-computer on (each of) a couple of these ships filled with rock. That is faster to develop than viable cryogenics and less likely to kill the passenger than anything involving surgery.

I appreciate that it *sounds* like futuristic tech, but this is applying principles that have been known for decades - you've provided all the handwavium.

Comment: "With that, you can make your ship-full-of-rock into something like a black hole by moving fast enough " do you mean to say that "mass at high enough relativistic speeds can act as backholes"? Because that's not the _today_'s understanding of the science - the [OMG particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle) don't exert more gravity on the environment - so you need a serious dose of the optimistic handwavium, something like "loading the ships with mini-blackholes and setting the human in the center"

Comment: I had understood differently, that the increased velocity did cause a gravitational effect, and that the OMG particle was a proton with the apparent mass of a baseball. And therefore with still-insignificant gravity, despite the ludicrous magnification. Since your understanding appears to be stronger here, I'll bow respectfully and merely hope that my answer can be of some use to someone else.

Having said that, the "free energy" thing remains plausible.

Comment: "I had understood differently" - here's [a simple enough correction](https://www.wtamu.edu/~cbaird/sq/2013/06/18/can-you-go-fast-enough-to-get-enough-mass-to-become-a-black-hole/).

Comment: Interesting. I based my model on the notion that that gravitation was governed by the mass-energy packed into a region of space, and that converting between mass and energy (say, mass-to-light-and-heat such as in a stellar core) didn't change the gravitational effects outside that region. (I.e. if you have a black hole which you inject 1GeV into, it doesn't matter if that's in the form of a photon or neutrons.) Your link doesn't address that directly, so should I take it that the KE does not have a gravitational effect?

Comment: "should I take it that the KE does not have a gravitational effect" I'll need to dig deep into now forgotten and fuzzy memories (something about stress-energy tensor in general relativity) to see exactly how you can't make a blackhole by increasing the speed of an a object close to the light speed. Until then, note that even if you set the human between two or more (close enough) black holes, you'll need to deal with the tidal forces. (see Niven's ["Neutron star"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_Star_(short_story)) for an enjoyable explanation)

Comment: Good story, thank you. The device I was envisioning would involve tidal forces, but not to introduce noticeable effects on a scale of one-human-length - scaling up the device to suit, and let the problems be someone else's. But we've established that I'd missed an assumption there.

Comment: "but not to introduce noticeable effects on a scale of one-human-length" - if you want to keep the human body in a Lagrange point of the two BH in such a way that _it will stay there at high acceleration_ (and not be left behind by the accelerating gravitational field), I'm afraid you will need to take tidal forces into consideration. Depending on the value of acceleration to be imparted, it may be a small negligible perturbation in the economy of forces or it may be at "drawn and quartered" values (one would need to do these calculations, but I'm missing the time to do it).

Answer (score 0):

It's been very thoroughly hushed up, but two of the world's governments got into contact with a competing "someone" who offered a different technology.  Originally aimed at much more primitive space launch methods (effectively, gun into space *a la* Jules Verne), the aim was to allow a *living human* to survive the effects of tens of thousands of G.

The process is called "vitrification" -- and involves *freezing* a living organism so quickly that none of the water in the tissues can crystallize, but instead forms an amorphous solid that, critically, does *not* expand by several percent volume.  It's a method that was known in theory as long ago as the mid-20th century, but could not be applied to most macroscopic organisms (bigger than the tiniest shrews, for instance) because of heat transfer limitations.

The "someone" in this case came up with a method to transfer heat out of (and, also critically, *into*) a body rapidly enough to achieve roundly 1000 °C per second cooling or warming through the range of temperature of interest (from around 40+ °C down to about -60 °C), allowing vitrification and revival of organisms without any other preparation requirements.  The process takes less than a second, and since biological processes are, well, frozen, it imperceptible to the subject; survival rates are reported as being above 99.5% for creatures the size of a human (less for larger creatures, better for smaller).

With a crew traveling in automatic vitrification beds, G levels can be such as to reach relativistic speeds in a matter of minutes -- but only for organizations with access to this technology.

The stars are in reach!  You can't go home again, however...

Comment: Not bad. But the technologies aren't quite today's one. As for the cosmic dust, no need to worry - the same thing that doesn't allow attachment or pushing into something takes care of "pushing into cosmic dust" too. I suspect that it may be something trans-dimensional that the engine-hull is using, because... ummm... no matter how much matter you throw at a functioning hull, it simply disappears, no radiation. no heating, not even the sound of disappearing with a "puff! It's gone" - just the "it's gone" part.

Comment: If that were in the question...  BTW, even without vitrification, the stars are open, given that.  One year (or so) at 1G and you're close enough to C for time dilation to be a major factor -- so anywhere in the universe is less than three or four years ship time.  Who cares if the Sun has burned out by the time you get there and get back...

Comment: @ZeissIcon "BTW, even without vitrification, the stars are open" the multinationals chase immediate profit. Why go to Alpha Centauri (with some 9-10 Earth-years return trip, including the exploration time there) when the competition eats your quarterly profit from the Solar system asteroid belt and Oort cloud. Set you claims in the Solar system, _then_ go further.

Comment: Pretty sure Musk will be aiming for places like Trappist 1 or Gliese 581 -- his profit machine can run itself, and if he doesn't like the view, he can turn around and come straight home and claim his trust (which, by then, should own everything Disney didn't manage to snatch up).  BTW, with vitrification, the two countries that bought in (I presumed USA and China, but it might have been India and Russian Federation) should be able to claim each planet, including its major moons, in a matter of days; after that, it's just a fight over the scraps.

Comment: @ZeissIcon "should be able to claim each planet, including its major moons" Careful with that, in the case of competing claims, the winner is the one that stands first in the center of the circle that defines the claim borders. You'll need a strategy that doesn't involve making the claim in the center of a planet. And now…  if you are too greedy and make a larger circle, your centripetal acceleration is going to be lower, which means you are going to finish traveling your circle in longer time than a competitor taking higher centripetal acceleration, so just carving a piece  you thought yours.

Answer (score 0):

**This human has neither bones nor nervous system.**

https://www.lubbockinfertility.com/blog/2019/04/01/how-long-do-frozen-embryos-197441

> What Is the Oldest Frozen Embryo Successfully Used?
>
> As of now, the oldest frozen embryo used was 24 years old. This frozen
> embryo was donated to a young couple in 2017; the mother was 26 years
> old at the time, and her husband experienced infertility due to cystic
> fibrosis.
>
> What Is the Oldest Frozen Embryo Available? Embryo freezing techniques
> were developed in 1984, though only came into popular use in the late
> 1980s. Given these facts, the oldest frozen embryo available would be
> about 30 years old, give or take.

Your human is an embryo of about 120 cells.  It is frozen solid in liquid nitrogen.  It rides along while the automatons on its supership trace out an immense circle over several decades.

On return the embryo is thawed, implanted and carried to term.  Once born it makes its claim.  A cell was removed and genotyped prior to its being frozen.  That genotype is used to confirm the identity of the human claiming the contents of the circle.

Other embryos are along for this ride.  Should there be some issue with one one chosen to make the claim, one of the others is thawed.

Comment: I hardly think that an embryo can make a valid legal claim on behalf of a corporation _today_. Waiting for the embryo to develop until reaches the age of legal consent, you'll have the competitors eat your claims within Solar system just by using chemical rockets. And if they make a successful claim on Ceres, their economic advantage in the future over you is overwhelming. Wake up, we're dealing with cut-throat competition.

Comment: I am awake.  You wanted tech to allow a human to survive a high acceleration trip: that is my answer.  As regards the legal rights of embryos or babies or anything else you can have your society make them what you need.

Comment: *Sure*.. if you can find a *donor* for providing the embryo !! Imagine being kept alive, alone in some space ship, with the sole purpose of performing silly legal rituals on arrival, on behalf of some multi-billionaire who payed for you and your travel. After signing this legal bla bla bla, you've served your purpose, you'll be  growing up in the middle of nowhere, on artificial food, with no future at all.. If treating children like this would be the result of the law imposed, any sensible parliament will abolish the requirement before the first victim would be able to claim anything.

Comment: @Willk there's more to the story in the context, it's not a freeform question.

Answer (score 0):

## Teleporter Victim Finds Fulfillment With Our Enlightened Corporation

Last year, flags at Gryydy Aerospace (1) flew at half mast in recognition of a terrible accident at Instaporter, a fully independent subcontractor (2) exclusively serving our Corporation.  Their first human test ended when the astronaut, whom we shall not name for privacy reasons, became intermeshed with a diamond bulkhead. (3) Theorists have been unable to explain the accident, let alone propose a safe way to undo the damage.

Today, however, the astronaut has found a new purpose, flying in our Preventative Claims Project.  Space may be mind-bogglingly huge, but our Corporation would not be well defended if we permitted rivals to complete a claim without beating them to the office.  Today our man stands at the ready to follow *any* launch by our hated rivals, track it to the site of record, and fly the required course in a fraction of the time any of their merely human astronauts can handle.

(1) Not to be confused with Griddy, of course.
(2) With its own bankruptcy and liability proceedings, and a bundle of third-party market capitalization just before its "unfortunate accident".
(3) As we are only speaking of current technology, there is no teleporter and there was no accident.  The "astronaut" was **3-D printed from scratch** in a diamond matrix using cloned cells to include the required systems and as much bracing as physically feasible.  This is related to organ 3D printing experiments that (with vanishingly weak plausibility) might be conducted at present, plus a branch of carbon material science that is often in the news even if we never see it.

Comment: /The "astronaut" was 3-D printed from scratch/ I see... I see your future... it shows decades of litigation on the meaning of "being a human"... it will only bring you misery and bad heart.. And, by the way, your wife will leave you and take the kids and 75% of your wealth, letting the rest to your beloved lawyers. (letting aside that 3D printing a fully functional human-like intelligence is _not_ even on the horizon of today technologies. Even only the silicon version of what they call AI today can't drive a car).

Comment: The way you put it, it doesn't sound all that bad.  (That's because you left out the patent litigation)